# Nested list in xamarin form for show Parent Child relation

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am working on android application using Xamarin form. I want to show Parent child records on view, for this purpose i have used nested list for this purpose. But i am getting error:- **Unable to activate instance of type Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ListViewAdapter from native handle 0xbece09ec (key_handle 0x6ac225f).** If anybody have any idea please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Do you really expect someone just to come up with some ideas for your problem without seeing a single line of your code?

Comment: I just asking to display data, if there is any alternate to display data instead of listview. Might be alternate can overcome the issue, so that i did not upload the code, just added the brief description.

Comment: Nested Lists are Really Bad Ideas